# Swap file with Btrfs and multiple device

Tags: swap, btrfs

**System specs:**

```
# btrfs filesystem show
Label: none  uuid: 3899c47c-19e8-4db3-aac9-....
    Total devices 2 FS bytes used 2.00TiB
    devid    1 size 931.42GiB used 690.01GiB path /dev/nvme1n1p2
    devid    2 size 1.86TiB used 1.63TiB path /dev/nvme0n1
```

kernel: 5.4 (ubuntu 20.04)

**My problem:**

I tried creating a swap file, either in a new subvolume, or as a file (/swapfile). I followed carefully the tutorials, so no COW and no compression.

However, when I try to do the swapon, I have the following error: `swapon failed: Invalid argument` and in `dmesg`: `BTRFS warning (device nvme1n1p2): swapfile must be on one device`

I don't have much expertise with Btrfs, it looks like the problem is that my FS is expanded on 2  disks, which is a problem for the swap. Is there a way to create the file, or subvolume on a specific FS?

Comment: it may be of zero help, but maybe you'll find something in: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation_into_a_thinly-provisioned_LVM_volume

Comment: it seems that btrfs does not support swap on multiple volumes, see the note in the swap section here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/btrfs#Swap_file